# What is preventing my input field from obeying css flexbox styles?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a widget that is composed of three subcomponents:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-width"></div>
  <div class="flex-width"></div>
  <div class="fixed-width"></div>
<div>
```

And I want the middle component to stretch or shrink based on the width of the container. For this I use flexbox:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.fixed-width {
  flex: 0 0 48px;
}
.flex-width {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

This works fine when the middle component is a `<div>`.
But when I change the middle component to an `<input>` element, the `<input>` element refuses to shrink to smaller than 173px for some reason.

I can fix it by putting the `<input>` in its own container, and give the input `width: 100%`, but I don't like creating extra DOM-elements for styling only, and I am curious why the `<input>` does not obey my flexbox settings.

What is preventing my `<input>` from obeying its css flexbox instructions?
Or is this a known 'bug' in css?

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of problematic flexbox sizing]

And [here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/GqVRPq?editors=0100) that demonstrates the isue:

Comment: A flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the length of its content. Just add `min-width: 0` to `input` (`.flex-width`) [revised pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqVgoW?editors=1100).

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it. I did not know of any (and did not find info on) default min-width for input elements. Feel free to post is as answer and I'll be happy to check it for rep.

Comment: Yeah, the more interesting question (for me in this case) is *what is the default width of an input type=text element?* .. It's 173px in Chrome, but its 143px in FF, and 153px in Edge. So clearly it's at the browsers discretion.

Comment: Noticed that too. Looking at the duplicate flag I guess my Q is already answered. Apparently I used the wrong keywords. Will vote over there. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is a plunkr that shows the min-width fix: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lzbdclb31AVuth4riRTU?p=preview